# Navigating to second div after page loads using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use javascript to navigate to the second div after the page loads, but it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
window.location.hash = "second"; 
</script>
```

```css
#first {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#second {
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'first'> </div>
<div id = 'second'> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your script runs *after* the document is loaded.  Since you've tagged jQuery, this should work:

```
$(function() {
  window.location.hash = "second";
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2787ycr0/)

Answer (score 0):

[Works for me](https://jsbin.com/qocoru/edit?html,css,js,output)! Be sure only that the javascript runs when the document is loaded, an easy way is to put it a the end of the document. If you want do it with jquery use [on document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).